# Images load from sdcard

Tags: java, android

i download about 100 pictures from my server inorder to show them in a listView,

therefore i save them in my sdcard that i will not receive a OutOfMemoryException.

however, i see that even if i download them to the sdcard, i must decode them to a Bitmap which takes alot of memory and then to show them, therefore i also get a "OutOfMemory" Exception.

is there anything to deal with it?

thanks alot

this is my code to load image from sdcard:

```
Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("path of img1");
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this code for loading the image from file:

```
 img.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(imagePath, 1000, 700));
```

when `decodeSampledBitmapFromFile`:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) 
{ // BEST QUALITY MATCH

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        }

        int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

        if (expectedWidth > reqWidth) {
            //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger SampSize..
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }
    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
  }
```

you can play with the number (1000, 700 in this case) to configure what quality the output of the image file would be.

Comment: thanks alot, i will try it, also what is the recommended parameters? that the image will not be so big and also keep on good quality?

Comment: if i want image till 0.2MByte, i will can also get a good resolution? maybe do you know about other way without using bitmap? or using way to load images from sdcard without load it to my app data space?

Comment: this was the way that helped me to avoid outOfMemory problems. and no I don't know any other way.

Comment: hi emil, thanks you, what is the parameters that you use for this function? please let me know

Comment: I used to 1000 and 700 for a full size image (one image on screen) and 150 and 100 for thumbnail images (many image on screen), laila tov ; )

Comment: thanks alot! i accepted your answer, i will be also happy for answer for my other question (if you can answer it): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913225/facebook-image-outofmemoryexception

Comment: sorry, I have no experience with Facebook.